# How to send multiple replies from flask webhook to facebook chatbot using dialogflow?

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

I want my facebook chatbot to send multiple responses at the same time.

For example:

When the user says:

Hey

The chatbot should respond with:

Hey!
How are you?

Currently using dialogflow and a webhook built using python to build responses.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But not in a way I consider clean.

You can add a response under the 'default' tab.
Under the 'facebook' tab you can than tick *Use response from the DEFAULT tab as the first response.*. This way two responses are send to facebook and to facebook only.

---

**But** you can send messages to the messenger via the facebook send api from your webhook at any time. Have a look at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api 
This has nothing to do with dialogflow though.

You can find the id of the facebook user in the payload, dialogflow send to your webhook.
Here is an example of where you can find it.

```
{:originalDetectIntentRequest
 {:payload
  {:source "facebook",
   :data
   {:recipient {:id "1144092719067446"},
    :sender {:id "1235572976569567"},       <== This is the id you are looking for!
    :timestamp 1.536065422409E12,
    :message
    {:mid
     "YzKAMwoJlAR0n3Vke2RJf83aVMGWzBnJ77SfUDe_NwkzIT1BBQXaWPVjN6Qf0xN4veairdW504PoKzcKV3lKBw",
     :seq 183071.0,
     :text "They are loyal"}}},
  :source "facebook"},
...
...}
```